# Dictionary Training For Different Language

Tags: dictionary

I am working on a messaging system and got the idea of storing the messages in each inbox independently. While working on that idea I asked myself why not compress the messages. So I am looking for a good way to optain dictionaries in different languages.

Since the messages are highly related to everydays talking (social bla bla) I need a good source and way for that.

I need some text for it like a bunch of millions emails, books etc. I would like to create a Huffman tree out of it with the ability to inline and represent each message as a string within this huffman tree. So decoding would be fast enough.

The languages I want to use are over the place. Since Newspapers and alike might not be sufficient I need other ways.

[Update]

As I countinue my research, I noticed that I actually create two dictionaries out of wikipedia. First is a dictionary containing typical characters with a certain propability. Also I noticed that special characters I used for each language seams to have even distribution among latain based languages (well actually latain is just one member of the language family) and even russians tend to have the same distribution beside the quite different alphabet.

Also I noticed that in around 15 to 18% a special character (like ' ', ',', ';') follows another special character. And by than the first 8 most frequent word yield 10% where the next 16 words yield 9% and going on and on and by around 128 (160 words) you reach a yield of 80% of all words. So storing the next 256 and more words, becomes senseless in terms of analysing. This leaves me behind with three dictionaries (characters, words, special characters) per language of around 2 to 5KB (I use a special format to use prefix compression) that save me between 30% to 60% in character reduction and also when you remember that in Java each character stores 16 bits it results in an overall reduction of even more making it a 1:5 to 1:10 by also compressing (huffman tree) the characters having to insert.

Using such a system and compressing numbers as variable length integers, one produces a byte array that can be used for String matching, loads faster and checking for words to contain is faster than doing character by character comparism since one can check for complete words more faster by not needing to tokenize or recognize words in the first place.

It solved the problem of supporting string keys since I just can transform the string in each language and it results in a set of keys I can use for lookups.

Comment: Wow here comes the close again. Please if you want this question to be closed, please tell me why and where to ask the question? This is about a valid programming afford so why?

Comment: If you experience negative feedback on your questions, I'd recommend having a look at the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lots of good information there.